# How can I access command line parameters in Rust?

Tags: command-line, rust

The [Rust tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/guessing-game.html) does not explain how to take parameters from the command line. `fn main()` is only shown with an empty parameter list in all examples.

What is the correct way of accessing command line parameters from `main`?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You can access the command line arguments by using the [`std::env::args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/fn.args.html) or [`std::env::args_os`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/fn.args_os.html) functions. Both functions return an iterator over the arguments. The former iterates over `String`s (that are easy to work with) but panics if one of the arguments is not valid unicode. The latter iterates over `OsString`s and never panics.

Note that the first element of the iterator is the name of the program itself (this is a convention in all major OSes), so the first argument is actually the second iterated element.

An easy way to deal with the result of `args` is to convert it to a `Vec`:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() > 1 {
        println!("The first argument is {}", args[1]);
    }
}
```

You can use the whole [standard iterator toolbox](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) to work with these arguments. For example, to retrieve only the first argument:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    // we use nth(1) for the first argument because
    // nth(0) traditionally corresponds to the binary path
    if let Some(arg1) = env::args().nth(1) {
        println!("The first argument is {}", arg1);
    }
}
```

You can find libraries on [crates.io](https://crates.io) for parsing command line arguments:

- [clap](https://crates.io/crates/clap): you describe the options you want to parse using a fluent API. Faster than docopt and gives you more control.
- [getopts](https://crates.io/crates/getopts): port of the popular C library. Lower-level and even more control.

Answer (score 29):

[Docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.rs) is also available for Rust, which generates a parser for you from a usage string. As a bonus in Rust, a macro can be used to automatically generate the struct and do type based decoding:

```
docopt!(Args, "
Usage: cp [-a] SOURCE DEST
       cp [-a] SOURCE... DIR

Options:
    -a, --archive  Copy everything.
")
```

And you can get the arguments with:

```
let args: Args = Args::docopt().decode().unwrap_or_else(|e| e.exit());
```

The README and [documentation](https://docs.rs/docopt) have plenty of full working examples.

Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of this library.

Comment: docopt has been unmaintained for a long time now. https://github.com/docopt/docopt.rs

Answer (score 12):

Rust has `getopt`-style CLI argument parsing in the [getopts crate](https://crates.io/crates/getopts).

Answer (score 10):

For me, getopts always felt too low-level and docopt.rs was too much magic.
I want something explicit and straightforward that still provides all the features if I need them.

This is where [clap-rs](https://github.com/kbknapp/clap-rs) comes in handy.
It feels a bit like argparse from Python.
Here is an example of how it looks like:

```
let matches = App::new("myapp")
                      .version("1.0")
                      .author("Kevin K. <kbknapp@gmail.com>")
                      .about("Does awesome things")
                      .arg(Arg::with_name("CONFIG")
                           .short("c")
                           .long("config")
                           .help("Sets a custom config file")
                           .takes_value(true))
                      .arg(Arg::with_name("INPUT")
                           .help("Sets the input file to use")
                           .required(true)
                           .index(1))
                      .arg(Arg::with_name("debug")
                           .short("d")
                           .multiple(true)
                           .help("Sets the level of debugging information"))
                      .get_matches();
```

You can access your parameters like so:

```
println!("Using input file: {}", matches.value_of("INPUT").unwrap());

// Gets a value for config if supplied by user, or defaults to "default.conf"
let config = matches.value_of("CONFIG").unwrap_or("default.conf");
println!("Value for config: {}", config);
```

(Copied from the [official documentation](https://github.com/kbknapp/clap-rs#quick-example))

Comment: I like that clap-rs lets you define your interface in a yaml file. Also, it produces really nice looking usage statements.

Comment: This helped me quickly set up my CLI app. Thank you!

Comment: Is this still up to date? The API in the documentation looks different now

Comment: Probably. I recommend clap-derive for new projects. It's more versatile and nicer to look at. https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/_tutorial

Answer (score 8):

I personally don't like using a library in smaller projects if it is not necessary and parsing commandline arguments in Rust is pretty straight forward:

```
fn main() {
    let config: String;

    let mut args = env::args().skip(1);
    while let Some(arg) = args.next() {
        match &arg[..] {
            "-h" | "--help" => help(),
            "--version" => {
                println!("{} {}", prog().unwrap_or_default(), VERSION);
            }
            "-q" | "--quiet" => {
                println!("Quiet mode is not supported yet.");
            }
            "-v" | "--verbose" => {
                println!("Verbose mode is not supported yet.");
            }
            "-c" | "--config" => {
                if let Some(arg_config) = args.next() {
                    config = arg_config;
                } else {
                    panic!("No value specified for parameter --config.");
                }
            }
            _ => {
                if arg.starts_with('-') {
                    println!("Unkown argument {}", arg);
                } else {
                    println!("Unkown positional argument {}", arg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to handle non-string arguments you can use the String::parse() method to try to parse the given string as the specified type:

```
"-s" | "--size" => {
    if let Some(arg_size) = arg_it.next() {
        size = arg_size
            .parse::<usize>()
            .expect("Size argument expects an integer value.");
    } else {
        panic!("No value specified for parameter size.");
    }
}
```

If you would like to handle values with an equal sign (`=`) instead of a whitespace, you can include the following code above the `match` clause and match the key value instead:

```
let (key, value) = match arg.contains('=') {
    true => {
        let str_vec: Vec<&str> = arg.split('=').collect();
        (String::from(str_vec[0]), Some(String::from(str_vec[1])))
    },
    false => {
        (arg, None)
    }
};
```

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 5):

As of version 0.8/0.9, the correct path to the function args() would be `::std::os::args`, i.e.:

```
fn main() {
  let args: ~[~str] = ::std::os::args();
  println(args[0]);
}
```

It seems that Rust is still pretty volatile right now with even standard I/O, so this may become out of date fairly quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Guess I will have to reconsider accepted answer after 1.0 is released.

Answer (score 4):

Also check out structopt:

```
extern crate structopt;
#[macro_use]
extern crate structopt_derive;

use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
#[structopt(name = "example", about = "An example of StructOpt usage.")]
struct Opt {
    /// A flag, true if used in the command line.
    #[structopt(short = "d", long = "debug", help = "Activate debug mode")]
    debug: bool,

    /// An argument of type float, with a default value.
    #[structopt(short = "s", long = "speed", help = "Set speed", default_value = "42")]
    speed: f64,

    /// Needed parameter, the first on the command line.
    #[structopt(help = "Input file")]
    input: String,

    /// An optional parameter, will be `None` if not present on the
    /// command line.
    #[structopt(help = "Output file, stdout if not present")]
    output: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let opt = Opt::from_args();
    println!("{:?}", opt);
}
```

https://github.com/TeXitoi/structopt

Comment: structopt is now available through clap, too.

Answer (score 3):

The [Rust book "No stdlib" chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/no-stdlib.html) covers how to access the command lines parameters (another way).

```
// Entry point for this program
#[start]
fn start(_argc: isize, _argv: *const *const u8) -> isize {
    0
}
```

Now, the example does also have `#![no_std]` which I think means that normally, the std library would have the true entry point for your binary  and call a global function called `main()`. Another options is to 'disable the `main` shim' with `#![no_main]`. Which if I'm not mistaken is saying to the compiler that you are taking full control over how your program is started.

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

#[no_mangle] // ensure that this symbol is called `main` in the output
pub extern fn main(argc: isize, argv: *const *const u8) -> isize {
    0
}
```

---

<sub>I do not think this is a 'good' way of doing things if all you want to do is read command line arguments. The `std::os` module mentioned in other answers seems to be a much better way of doing things. I post this answer for the sake of completion.</sub>

Comment: Amazing. After like half an hour of reading the docs and search results, **this** is the first way I've found for getting the actual argument bytes without them needing to decode to valid Unicode. I have no idea how Rust got this far as a language without a better way to handle the edge case of "I have received invalid Unicode as a CLI argument, and it's not my job to question whether or not it's valid, my job is to pass it along to some other program/library". *sigh* +1

Comment: Dead link for that rust book no stdlib chapter, btw.

Answer (score 3):

Rust changed again. `os::args()` is deprecated in favor of `std::args()`. But `std::args()` is not an array, it returns an *iterator*. You can iterate over the command line arguments, but cannot access them with subscripts.

http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.args.html

If you want the command line arguments as a vector of strings, this will work now:

```
use std::env;
...
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().map(|s| s.into_string().unwrap()).collect();
```

*Rust - learn to embrace the pain of change.*

Comment: You now need only do `env::args().collect()`.

Answer (score 2):

What [barjak said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619320/how-can-i-access-command-line-parameters/15621897#15621897) works for strings, but if you need the argument as a number (in this case a uint) you need to convert like this:

```
fn main() {
    let arg : ~[~str] = os::args();
    match uint::from_str(arg[1]){
         Some(x)=>io::println(fmt!("%u",someFunction(x))),
         None=>io::println("I need a real number")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate over command-line arguments:

```
use std::env::{args,Args};

fn main() {
    let mut args:Args=args();
    // args.nth(0) cannot borrow as mutable. that is why  let mut args
    // nth return an element of iterator
    let first=args.nth(1).unwrap();
    // iterator has next method. we want to get the first element of next iterator. NOT args.nth(2)
    // chars returns an iterator
    let operator=args.nth(0).unwrap().chars().next().unwrap();
    let second=args.nth(0).unwrap();
}
```

If you want to access the n'th argument directly:

```
fn get_nth_arg(n:usize)->String{
    std::env::args().nth(n).unwrap()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>As of newer Rust versions (Rust > 0.10/11) the array syntax won't work. You will have to use the get method.</s>

The array syntax works (again) in the nightly. So you can choose between the getter or array index.

```
use std::os;

fn main() {
  let args = os::args();
  println!("{}", args.get(1));
}

// Compile
rustc args.rs && ./args hello-world // returns hello-world
```

Comment: This is obsolete statement. Latest Rust nightlies do support indexing syntax on `Vec`s. I guess it is there for a month or so. See [this example](http://is.gd/YRvx3C).

Answer (score 1):

Rust has evolved since [Calvin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619320/how-can-i-access-command-line-parameters/16500034#16500034) from May 2013. Now one would parse command line arguments with `as_slice()`:

```
use std::os;

fn seen_arg(x: uint)
{       
    println!("you passed me {}", x);
}
fn main() {
    let args = os::args();
    let args = args.as_slice();
    let nitems = {
            if args.len() == 2 {
                    from_str::<uint>(args[1].as_slice()).unwrap()
            } else {
                    10000
            }
    };

    seen_arg(nitems);
}
```

Comment: Just for the record: `as_slice()` doesn't exist anymore and `&args` should be used instead.