# Rust: Attempting to read i32 command line arguments causes a code panic

Tags: rust

I've tried using the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619320/how-can-i-access-command-line-parameters-in-rust) to read command line arguments as strings and the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043268/convert-a-string-to-int) to convert strings to integers. However, when I run the code using "cargo run 1 2 3" instead of getting 6 as an output I get an error saying

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()`  
> on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src/main.rs:7:45

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. As far as I'm concerned I did essentially the same thing as the answers marked correct in the two threads I linked above.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let first: i32 = args[0].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
    let second: i32 = args[1].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
    let third: i32 = args[2].parse::<i32>().unwrap();

    let result: i32 = first * second * third;

    println!("The product of your three arguments is {result}.");
}
```

Comment: To pass arguments to your program (and not to cargo), prepend them with `--`, i.e. `cargo run -- 1 2 3`.

Comment: I tried using "cargo run -- 1 2 3". I still got the same error except that the 7:45 was replaced with 6:45.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942775/what-do-two-dashes-mean-in-cargo

Comment: Skip the first argument, otherwise it will try to interpret the program's name as an integer.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger I removed the duplicate because there's also the problem Cerberus mentioned.